# BPMN: 2 Actors Did The Same Task Together

Tags: task, actor, bpmn

So I have a process, which VP and SVP doing the same task evaluation like collaboration
But I know that 1 Lane only for 1 Actor, so how to draw it in BPMN?

Answer (score 0):

A lane does not have to represent a single role / person. It can also represent organizational units (group of users,...).
Either use an abstract description of the group performing the tasks together or use two lanes if you want to model more detail.